# Removing the field name from a worksheet

Tags: tableau-desktop

I've got a worksheet in Tableau.  The field name is Status, and the worksheet shows the count of all possible statuses.  I can't paste pics due to an IT policy at my company, but it looks something like this:

```
                           Status
Enabled         Disabled            Expired       Inactive
  456             621                  752           47
```

What I want to do is remove (or change) the word "Status" from the display.  It's not a title, it's the field name that's in the Columns "pillbox" at the top of the worksheet.  If I can't remove it, I'd like to rename it "Registered User Status".  Is this possible?  If so, how?  I'm very new to Tableau, so please be descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the label by right-clicking on it

[image]